# How to return two variables in SQL functions

Tags: sql, function, sqlplus

I have to write a SQL function that returns two values: `IDSHOPPER` and `ORDERPLACED`. But I get an error.

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT UNIQUE IDSHOPPER, ORDERPLACED 
FROM BB_BASKET 
WHERE ORDERPLACED = (SELECT MIN(orderplaced) FROM BB_BASKET);
```

and it returns this response which is correct:

```
IDSHOPPER ORDERPLACED
---------- -----------
        26           0
```

But I don't know how to return two values from the function. My function is shown here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ORD_PLACED
RETURN object
IS 
   c number(2) := 0; 
   
BEGIN 
   SELECT UNIQUE IDSHOPPER,ORDERPLACED FROM BB_BASKET WHERE ORDERPLACED=(SELECT  MIN(orderplaced) FROM BB_BASKET );
END; 
/
```

Data in table:

```
IDBASKET ORDERPLACED
---------- -----------
         3           1
         4           1
         5           1
         6           1
         7           1
         8           1
         9           1
        10           1
        11           1
        12           1
        13           0

  IDBASKET ORDERPLACED
---------- -----------
        14           0
```

Question : Create a function ORD_PLACED that will identify the customer with lowest total amount of order. Refer to table BB_BASKET that include IDSHOPPER column which represents customer id. Display the idshopper and the total amount of the order.

Comment: Functions can only return a single value by design. Are you possibly intending to create a stored procedure instead?

Comment: yes - not to make an argument - but the query doesn't sound right...  Give me back one (of possibly many) shopper id numbers that match to the lowest amount of orders, and by the way how many orders did they make. (mostly 0).  so how many of those do you expect? is this really a check on some UI that is allowing a bad condition to exist?

Comment: Question: Create a function ORD_PLACED that will identify the customer with lowest total amount of order. Refer to table BB_BASKET that include IDSHOPPER column which represents customer id. Display the idshopper and the total amount of the order.

Comment: IDBASKET ORDERPLACED
---------- -----------
         3           1
         4           1
         5           1
         6           1
         7           1
         8           1
         9           1
        10           1
        11           1
        12           1
        13           0

  IDBASKET ORDERPLACED
---------- -----------
        14           0